# "The Go Programming Language" - is the article necessary?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

https://golang.org/

Not a native speaker. To me it sounds weird. I'd say "Go programming language".

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane. What if the name of the language was not an actual word? For example "C programming language".

Comment: To restore the comment, I wrote — An article is necessary, "Go programming language" seems like a grammatical error concerning the verb "to go". Compare with "I use hammer" where the article is also needed. — but I deleted it because it needs more context. There are situations where an article is used, and where it is not, so the question is quite broad, about the use of articles generally.

Comment: From https://tip.golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang some people call it Golang to avoid confusion- **especially** as a label for google searches or twitter references.

Comment: The article would be used similarly for FORTRAN, Basic, Java, C, et al.  Why should "Go" be treated differently?

Comment: @Alex it'd still be "The C Programming Language"―in fact that was the name of [the  original authoritative book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) on the subject co-authored by the creator of the C language.  "The Go Programming Language" is not only grammatically correct, but probably an intentional allusion to programmer lore as well.

Comment: @TrevorReid of course! How could I forget that :) Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article is necessary when you specify what Go is. "I can program in Go" will be comprehensible to software developers, but you might say "I can program in the Go programming language" to others, if you wanted to make sure that they understood.

Comment: Many non-programmers would assume from the context that Go is a programming language.

Comment: Ah so it's like "English" vs "the English language". I remember that rule now :)

Comment: Think of it this way: "Go" is acting like an adjective here. The article actually mofifies "language".

Comment: @CJDennis That's true but if someone said "I'm good at Go" you wouldn't know whether they meant the programming language or the strategy game unless there was some other context. Sometimes we need to be specific.

Comment: @Spencer You're talking about a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: @BoldBen I didn't say there would always be enough context to disambiguate. If you say "I can program in Go", it's obvious you're not talking about the game Go, but the programming language Go. Adding "the programming language" is still grammatically correct but semantically redundant.

Comment: @CJDennis It also depends who you're talking to, I've used a number of different languages and development environments professionally but I've never come across Go, probably because it came out after I retired. I would not have been sure, had I heard someone say "I can program in Go", whether they meant a language, an operating system, a design or analysis protocol or even a physical environment. Some less IT-aware people would have even less idea.

Answer (score 0):

The article is necessary because "the Go programming language" means exactly the same as "the programming language called 'Go'."  Here "Go" is a proper noun, being used as a modifier on the noun "language".  No different from "the Russian language".  Since "language" is a fairly vanilla countable noun, it is given an article in situations where an article is appropriate for such nouns.